# How do we know restart in cloudhub done automatically or Manual?

Tags: mule, mule4, cloudhub, anypoint-platform

how do we know the restart happened in anypoint Runtime Manager (cloudhub) is automatically restarted (due to some internal issue) or some one manually force restart?

How could we find that? any specific log line which could differentiate manual and automatic restart?  Any thoughts on it. Thanks

Using Version 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

The manual restart should be visible in the Audit Log. I don't think that the automatic restart due to a crash appears at all. Automatic restarts due to patching will be visible.

Comment: Thanks @aled. What do you mean by audit logs here. Do you mean we need to specifically config logger for that ( to get that line in the cloudhub logs). Expecting some lines in the logs come thing similar  Link: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/CloudHub-Application-Automatically-Restarted-by-Anypoint-Staff. Can you pass some example logs or link to refer. Thanks

Comment: The Audit logging is not a traditional log, it is an auditing log in the Access Management section: https://docs.mulesoft.com/access-management/audit-logging